# SQL count query - how to get desired results?

Tags: sql

I have a factory that contains 4 production lines, work in a year which is devised into periods of year. I also have a working days and holidays table that contains these columns:

```
factory_id, mainline_id, year_id, period_id, holiday check
```

`Holiday check` is a boolean column; it's true when the day is holiday, false when it's working day

I want to count all working days in a period of the year that belongs to specific mainline which is belong to specific factory

I tried

```
select count(holiday_check) 
from myTable 
where holiday_check = false
```

but it returns all working days in all periods and all years for all factories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table
WHERE  holiday_check = false
GROUP BY period_id, factory_id, mainline_id
```

Comment: i don't have specific condition  i want it to be grouped by period_id.. then count working days in each period that related to specific mainline which belong to specific factory